# Внедрение зависимости в статическое поле Micronaut 2

Tags: java, static, dependency-injection, bean

У меня есть фабричный класс который создает объект. Например, ObjectMapper (Jackson).

```
@Factory
public class JacksonFactory {

  @Singleton
  public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  }

}
```

Я хочу внедрить зависимость в статическое поле класса:

```
public class JsonString {

  @Inject
  private static ObjectMapper mapper;

  public static String of(Object object) {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

}
```

Но, так не получится. Я получу NullPointer каждый раз когда обращусь к статическому полю mapper. Если сделать методы и поле не статическими, обычный объект, все работает хорошо.

Я не нашел в документации объяснения этому, возможно я что-то упускаю или в чем проблема с внедрением зависимости?

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: в чем смысл держать это поле статическим?

Comment: Зачем вообще тут фабрика?

Comment: @tym32167 Я понимаю что DI используется для конструирования объектов, но я не понимаю в чем проблема инициализировать поле класса, так же как и поле объекта, даже в теории?
Проблема в том что мне из httpClient приходит Dto в котором мне нужно использовать сервис для переопределения toString. Но, так как заинжектить сервис в Dto я не могу, потому что объект создается не DI Micronaut, то я думал вынести сервис в статическое поле и по логике оно инжектится.
Но, так не работает и мне придется в статическом поле создавать объект через new. И в итоге будет два объекта в памяти, хотя это singleton.

Comment: DI для того и существует, чтобы контролировать создание объектов и их время жизни. А вы своим статическим полем хотите этот контроль сломать. Факт того, что объект является синглтоном должен храниться в настройках DI, а не в ваших статических полях.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, но это не работает в этой ситуации. HttpClient постоянно создает новые DTO, и заинжектить в них синглтон зависимость не выходит. Так как процесс создания объекта в не DI Micronaut на сколько я понимаю. 
То есть логика - все объекты получают ссылку на один объект сервис через DI не работает. И поэтому я решил вынести переменную на уровень класса и заинжектить туда через DI, так как inject в стат. поля не работает, но так тоже получиться, только если создать сервис самостоятельно :(